What is the intuition to create an orthogonal design matrix in an iterative way (without Gram-Schmidt)?

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be $n$ observations between $[-1,1]$ and
$X_i \ne X_j$ if $i\ne j$.   Let $\phi_0(x)=1$, $\phi_1(x) =
> 2(x-a_1)\phi_0(x)$.
When $r\ge 1$, $\phi_{r+1}(x)=2(x-a_{r+1})\phi_r(x)-b_r\phi_{r-1}(x)$.
Where $a_1=\bar{x}$, $b_0=0$ and  $$
    a_{r+1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi_r^2(x_i)x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi_r^2(x_i)},
    b_{r} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi_r^2(x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi_{r-1}^2(x_i)}
    $$ The design matrix $(\phi_r(x_i))_{n\times n}$ has orthogonal columns.

I've taken some numerical experiments and find it is true. More interestingly, if the design matrix has more than $n$ column, then the column with index greater than $n$ are all zeors!
It seems that this procedure is trying to do some projection. I think (x-$a_r$) seems like residuals and $b_r$ is like correlation. But I cannot prove it. I also expect an elegent and intuitive explanation for this strange procedure since it magically create orthogonal bases without Gram-Schmidt procedure.

It's probably a recursion you can derive for the orthogonal polynomials at the given nodes $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Like https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253123/what-are-multivariate-orthogonal-polynomials-as-computed-in-r&ved=2ahUKEwibmPnC0pyGAxWvMmIAHeEVCCAQFnoECCsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2-nhuvunKuzgVlnZXoRMqO
